# Batch - Using Modulo in a FOR Loop - Error Operand

Tags: loops, batch-file, modulo, operand

I've been trying to use MOD (%%) in order to make a timeout /t 3 command every 25 loops
I am getting an error "invalid operand"
Code is:

```
set /a var1=0
FOR /R "folder" %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd %%G
set /a b=%%var1%% %% 25
 IF %%b%% EQU 0 (
    timeout /t 3
  )
 set /a var1=%%var1%%+1
 Popd
)
```

Comment: Well I managed to get out of the invalid operand but I can't seem to get the modulo operator to work

Comment: You just need `%var1%`, not `%%var1%%`.

Comment: @SomethingDark, in general you are right, but here delayed expansion is required (at least for `!b!`)...

Answer (score 2):

[aschipfl has identified the problem and provided a fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730464/1012053). But there is a very concise and efficient way to accomplish your goal without any delayed expansion using only a single SET /A statement.

You can combine multiple computations and assignments within one SET /A. You can even use the result of an assignment expression within an even larger expression.

You can avoid an IF statement by intentionally dividing by zero. When the modulo result is 0, the division fails, and any error messages are hidden by redirecting stderr to nul. The conditional `||` command concatenation operator only fires if the preceding command failed, in this case when dividing by 0.

I don't understand the purpose of your loop - it seems pointless. But the correct pause is introduced with the following:

```
set /a var1=0
for /r "folder" %%G in (.) do (
  pushd "%%~G"
  set /a "1/((var1+=1) %% 25)" 2>nul || timeout /t 3
  popd
)
```

Comment: Sneaky! I love your answers because I always learn something new.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: Also, I have deleted some code in between the loop and outside the loop for personal reasons, so that's why you don't see a purpose for my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you enclosing variable names in pairs of `%` signs? The usual syntax for reading a variable is `%var1%`.

`set /A` can read variables even without percent signs around, so use `set /a b=var1 %% 25`.
The other `set /A` command line can be changed to `set /A var1+=1`.

There is one problematic variable in your code, namely `b`, because you are writing *and* reading it within the same (parenthesised) block of code, so `%b%` is read when the entire `for` loop is parsed, at which point it is empty most probably.
For such cases, you need to apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), so the variable is read at execution time. To enable it, use the `setlocal` command; to actually use it, write `!b!` instead of `%b%`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
set /A var1=0
for /R "folder" %%G in (.) do (
    pushd "%%~G"
    set /A b=var1 %% 25
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if !b! EQU 0 (
        timeout /T 3
    )
    endlocal
    set /A var1+=1
    popd
)
```

Here I placed `setlocal` and `endlocal` inside the loop so that delayed expansion is disabled during expansion (reading) of the `for` loop variable `%%G`, because in case it contains exclamation marks, they would get lost otherwise.